# On compressing series of ones and zeroes

Tags: c, compression

I'm in need of compressing a series of 1 and 0 like this one

http://cid-f328e92ab80e3d64.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/bits.txt

Can anyone suggest me what coder to user to achieve best compression(Huffman, arithmetic, BWT, LZW, RLE, PAQ ...)

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

With respect,
Chuckie

P.S. I found that bwtmix goes down to 577 bytes, but it is written in c++ and i need it in c.

Comment: What kind of computer would compress something else than 1s and 0s ?

Comment: just converting the text into pure binary gets it down to 714 bytes. unforunately it's not a multiple of 8 bytes though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Python program, by simply converting the ones and zeros into bytes, compresses it down to 715 bytes including a 16-bit leading count. Unfortunately, then standard compression programs zip, gzip, and bzip2 don't seem to be able to get any more compression out of it.

```
import sys, struct
i, n, b, count = 0, 0, '', 0
for byte in open('/tmp/binary.txt').read().rstrip():
 n = (n << 1) | (ord(byte) & 1)
 i = (i + 1) % 8
 if i == 0:
  n, b = 0, b + chr(n)
 count += 1
sys.stdout.write(struct.pack('<h', count) + b)
```

Comment: I know the code is inefficient, it's just proof-of-concept. I know you want it in C, and this is low-level enough that it shouldn't be too hard to port.

Comment: This is great, but I kind of need it to go below 600 bytes if possible.

Comment: That data looks fairly random to me (good compression could just make it larger). Maybe with about 10 KiB of complex code you might save 100 bytes if you're lucky (but if you can't see a problem with "10 KiB more for 100 bytes less" then...)